# Is it possible to enable in browser settings 'On startup - Continue where you left off' with Playwright/Puppeter on javascript?

Tags: javascript, automation

I need to open a browser and switch to the current page (e.g. stackoverflow.com) then close the browser and open it again with this saved page (e.g. stackoverflow.com). I know that in the browser settings you can make it so that when you open it you can start from where you closed the browser. That is, all tabs will be saved when opened. Is it possible to do this with Puppeteer?

I tried looking for flags, cannot find anything useful, and I would  really like a solution that does not rely on saving all open tabs then opening again